# What is the proper way to completely print out a list in Python

Tags: python, list, printing

I'm trying to create a simple program to print out the binary number of any given number under 255. I have everything working except printing out the final list.

I have a list called keyList and I've tried searching for an answer, but haven't found anything helpful. I assume you could use

`print(keyList)` or `print(keyList[])`

Variable Creation:

```
n = input("Enter Deciaml Number:")


def binaryKey(n):
    n = 0
    keyList = []
```

Printing Snippet:

```
print(keyList[])
```

No matter what I try changing, I always get the error: `NameError: name 'keyList' is not defined` This makes me think that my list name is wrong, but clearly it isn't.

Comment: its just `print(keyList)`. it appears you are trying to print it before its made or after its destroyed. are you aware of scopes? if you create something in a function it gets destroyed at the end of the function. return keyList from the function to have access to it outside the scope

Comment: Where is your "printing snippet" relative to the rest of your code? Is it inside `binaryKey`? Your error has nothing to do with your syntax (though as Nullman points out you're using the wrong syntax now). It's because the variable isn't in scope.

Comment: If you define `keyList` in a function, you can’t access it outside of the function unless you make it a global variable.

Comment: I would recommend reading some basic Python tutorials on variables, and as already mentiones, scopes.

Comment: `print(keyList[])` tries to index into the (out of scope) variable `keylist` without providing an index. Please take a look at some beginner tutorials for python, f.e. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists how to work with lists and functions:https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions

Comment: Doing the tutorial would help... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared kelist inside a function which you never used.
This is working example:

```
keylist = []
keylist.append('3')
keylist.append('2')
keylist.append('1')
print(keylist)
```

Output:

```
['3', '2', '1']
```